# call Custom phtml in footer through local.xml

Tags: xml, magento

My code in local.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
        <reference name="footer">
            <block type="core/template" name="site_access" as="site_access" template="folder_name/popup.phtml"/>
        </reference>        
</layout>
```

=>footer.phtml

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml(); ?>
```

but it does not display anything,
pls help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put code in local.xml() (app/design/frontend/{your theme}/default/layout/local.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
<default>
<reference name="footer">
<block type="core/template" name="mylogic" template="mylogic/mylogic.phtml"/>
</reference>
</default>
</layout>
```

write this in your footer.html

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('mylogic') ?>
```